# Image Not Loading (WordPress Template)

Tags: php

Im adding an image to my wordpress theme through dreamweaver cs4 and themedreamer. The image will go in the sidebar.php. When I inserted an image it doesnt shows in firefox and explorer. With safari, the image only shows an empty box with a question sign in the middle.

Is there a special way to add image in a wordpress template?

Answer (score 1):

Prepend below line to images's `src`:

```
<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>
```

Making your `src` something like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/yourimage.gif" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you have to get the value of the `src` attribute correct.